# Does any way to automate snaphot processing for Cassandra on the AWS?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, cassandra

I have a Cassandra cluster on AWS.
i would like to make some process which will make a snapshot of my Cassandra nodes and put them to S3 periodically.

Can i do that somehow?

Regards,
Yauheni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following:

https://github.com/winglian/SSTable2S3